# Data.table - efficient evaluation of expression in "j" during group by

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way of using / evaluating a string expression other than `eval(parse(text = ...))` ? The example below works fine, but it is quite literally a thousand times slower than "regular" code.
From what I can tell, `eval(parse())` works fine(time-wise) in both the `i` and the `j` terms unless `by` in used. I used `verbose=TRUE` and `GForce` is not used when using an expression, so I guess the question is how to use both `GForce` and the expression.

```
library(data.table)

N = 10**5
DT = data.table(x1 = sample(1:1000, size = N , replace = TRUE),
                x2 = sample(1:500, size = N , replace = TRUE),
                y1 = runif(N,1,10),
                y2 = runif(N,0,1))

system.time({
  DT_agg = DT[, .(sum_y1 = sum(y1)), by = c('x1','x2'), verbose=TRUE]
})
# Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE)
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.02    0.00    0.02 

expr = "sum_y1 = sum(y1)"
system.time({
  DT_agg = DT[, .(eval(parse(text = expr))), by = c('x1','x2'), verbose=TRUE]
})
# Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE)
# user  system elapsed 
# 27.72    0.00   28.11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the question is how to use both GForce and the expression.

If you (1) put the entire j argument in the expression and (2) parse it beforehand, it works:

```
> expr2 = quote(.(sum_y1 = sum(y1)))
> DT[, eval(expr2), by=c("x1", "x2"), verbose=TRUE]
Detected that j uses these columns: y1 
Finding groups using forderv ... 0.000sec 
Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.020sec 
Getting back original order ... 0.000sec 
lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(sum(y1))'
GForce optimized j to 'list(gsum(y1))'
Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... 0.010sec 
        x1  x2   sum_y1
    1: 377 368 1.293758
    2: 233 276 1.613304
    3: 190  97 3.432189
    4: 200 373 3.573958
    5: 924 345 5.535074
   ---                 
90538: 316 155 5.067798
90539: 960 180 5.788466
90540: 777 466 9.949981
90541: 520  43 3.815545
90542: 977 498 3.839360
```

Comment: Although the answer solves the issue I was having and does make `data.table` use `GForce`, the expression is not the evaluation of a string. Should I post a different question or is the answer easily updatable?

Comment: @BogdanC Not sure I follow. You need to parse the string before you pass it to DT[...]; otherwise, GForce won't kick in. If for some reason you must start with your original string, this means `p = parse(text = sprintf(".(%s)", expr))` then `DT[, eval(p), by=.(x1,x2), verbose=TRUE]` -- two steps.

Comment: This is great, wish I could upvote twice. I really need to get up to speed on how `eval`, `parse` and `quote` work.